# How to convert DateTime to a String

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display a `DateTime` as text in a `ListTile`.

What I have done gives me the message:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'

Code:

```
_getDate() {
    String formattedDate = DateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd).format(widget.exampleForDate.myDate);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(formattedDate),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is `widget.exampleForDate.myDate` a `DateTime` object or `String`?

Comment: It is a DateTime object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to access `DateFormat`

```
DateTime dateTime = widget.exampleForDate.myDate; // your dateTime object
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // how you want it to be formatted
String string = dateFormat.format(dateTime); // format it
```

Use it like

```
ListTile(title: Text(string));
```

Comment: Now get the message: "The argument type Timestamp can't be assigned to the parameter type DateTime

Comment: Where are you using `string`, it should be in `ListTile(title: Text(string))`

Comment: It works like the answer given now, string is in listTile but I need to show my widgets date and not the current date

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple in Java Script **Date().toString()**